# How can I get woocommerce order number using email or phone number?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I am using

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
```

(using a web form)for fetching customer details related to that `order id`. I just want to be able to fetch customer details like `billing` and `shipping` address using customer's billing email or billing phone from database. thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$address    = $order->get_shipping_address();
$address    = $order->get_billing_address();
$order->billing_phone;
$order->billing_email;
```

Comment: in some cases I don't know the $order_id , by html form I want to fetch all details of a customer by sending billing email via post method to database.
I hope you understand what I am saying, thank you. 
PS. this is exactly what I am using currently to fetch customer details using order number($order_id). but in some cases I don't know the order number and I just know customers email and phone. I don't want to go into dashboard and find customer order number manually every time.

Comment: for using $order = new WC_Order($order_id); we need to get $order_id from somewhere right? like post method from html web form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try via:

```
$customer_id = get_current_user_id();
print get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );
print get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_email', true );
```

honestly, not tested

Comment: I think this is func is for getting order id of currently logged in user, however I wanted to fetch order id associated with any customers email or phone from database

Comment: @EnteamXrex, actually this answer is the closest one.. you can use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by to get the customer id by email..

Answer (score 1):

My solution for getting order id associated with particular email or phone number was as follows:

```php
global $wpdb; 
$postemail = $_POST["email"]; 
$bil_id = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        'SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = "_billing_email" AND meta_value = %s',$postemail)); 
    
echo $bil_id[0]->post_id;
```

To get the order id associated with billing phone replace `"_billing_email"` with `"_billing_phone"`, `meta_value = %s` with `meta_value = %d`

Answer (score 0):

No, not really, if you developing module you can use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array('Wc_class', 'create_some_stuff'));


class Wc_class{

 public static function create_some_stuff($order_id){
 $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
 $address    = $order->get_shipping_address();
}
```

and there will be no  error

Comment: Thank you for your help Arturas, it was my bad I couldn't explain what I need exactly, anyway my solution was as follow

`code`
global $wpdb;
$postemail = $_POST["email"];

$bil_id = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "_billing_email" AND meta_value = %s',$postemail));
echo $bil_id[0]->post_id;  `code`

Answer (score 0):

You could use WC's function `wc_get_orders()` to get orders by user email or phone:

```php
$ar_args   = array(
    // use 'billing_phone' as key if you want to search order(s) by phone
    'billing_email' => 'user@ema.il',
);
$ar_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

In this case, `$ar_orders` will contain array of WC_Order objects made by customers with `user@ema.il` as billing email. Or empty array if no one match.

You could use many other parameters to make order search more specific. I.e., if you need get only order ids, instead of objects, add `return` key to arguments array with value `ids`:

```php
$ar_args   = array(
    'billing_email' => 'user@ema.il',
    'return'        => 'ids',
);
$ar_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Read more about [`wc_get_orders()` on WC Wiki](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)